# Monitor idle threads in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, threadpool

Is there a quick way to monitor total no of idle threads in tomcat thread pool in runtime?

Something would be useful like :

```
Say suppose total of threads in thread pool : (m + n) , Would like to see something like :

Num of working threads : m 
Num of idle threads : n
```

I understand, if I attach an agent like yourkit, JMX - it could be achieved. But anything other than that where I can dump this info at certain intervals?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tomcat manager app (in-built) which does the same.